# Can't change /Contents of annotation

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to change the text in some PDF annotations using iTextSharp.  Here is my code:

```
    void changeAnnotations(string inputPath, string outputPath)
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(inputPath);
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create));

        //get the PdfDictionary of the 1st page
        PdfDictionary pageDict = pdfReader.GetPageN(1);

        //get annotation array
        PdfArray annotArray = pageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

        //iterate through annotation array
        int size = annotArray.Size;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {

            //get value of /Contents
            PdfDictionary dict = annotArray.GetAsDict(i);
            PdfString contents = dict.GetAsString(PdfName.CONTENTS);

            //check if /Contents key exists
            if (contents != null)
            {

                //set new value
                dict.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString("value has been changed"));
            }
        }
        pdfStamper.Close();
    }
```

When I open the output file in Adobe Reader, none of the text has changed in any of the annotations.  How should I be setting the new value in an annotation?

UPDATE: I've found that the value is being changed in the popup box that appears when I click on the annotation.  And in some cases, when I modify this value in the popup box, the change is then applied to the annotation.

Comment: You don't check whether the annotation in question has an appearance stream. If it does, PDF viewers may choose to simply display the annotation as pre-defined in that stream instead of generating an own appearance. Furthermore, the **Contents** may or may not be text displayed for an annotation, cf. the specification: *Text that shall be displayed for the annotation or, if this type of
annotation does not display text, an alternate description of the
annotation’s contents in human-readable form*.

Comment: @mkl, I can't figure out how to determine if there is an appearance stream.  Is that the `/AP` property?  I checked that for one of the annotations and it's a dictionary with a single entry whose value is `28 0 R`, but none of the items in `annotArray` have that value.  This annotation is a `FreeText`, how do I find and change the text that's displayed in this text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP clarified in a comment:

> This annotation is a `FreeText`, how do I find and change the text that's displayed in this text box?

Free text annotations allow a number of mechanisms to set the displayed text:

- A pre-formatted appearance stream, referenced by the **N** entry in the **AP** dictionary
- A rich text string with a default style string given in **RC** and **DS** respectively
- A default appearance string applied to the contents given in **DA** and **Contents** respectively

(For details cf. the PDF specification [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 12.5.6.6 *Free Text Annotations*)

**If you want to change the text using one of these mechanisms, make sure you remove or adjust the contents of the entries for the other mechanisms; otherwise your change might not be visible or even visible on some viewers but not visible on others.**

> I can't figure out how to determine if there is an appearance stream. Is that the `/AP` property? I checked that for one of the annotations and it's a dictionary with a single entry whose value is `28 0 R`.

So that *one of the annotations* indeed comes with an appearance stream. The *single entry whose value is `28 0 R`* presumably has the **N** name to indicate the *normal* appearance. `28 0 R` is a reference to the indirect object with object number `28` and generation `0`.

If you want to change the text content but do not want to deal with the formatting details, you should remove the **AP** entry.

Comment: Removing the **AP** key from each annotation resolved this issue.  Are there any risks with removing this key, e.g., are there certain Adobe Reader/Acrobat features that will fail if an annotation doesn't have this key?

Comment: The major risk is that there are some simple PDF viewers (mostly so-called previewers) which rely on appearance streams being present and don't have any code to create them on their own. These viewers will not render your annotation at all after **AP** removal.

Comment: Yes, I discovered that they don't display in Outlook's preview.  Is there another way to accomplish this?  See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014984/how-to-read-text-of-appearance-stream) that I just posted; in both cases, the solution involves identifying where the appearance text is set.

Comment: *Yes, I discovered that they don't display in Outlook's preview. Is there another way to accomplish this* - Well, to make every viewer happy, you will have to create appearance streams.